# Explicit Waits in page object model

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use the Explicit Waits in page object model to test a single page app , The problem i am facing is that the Explicit wait starts checking for the element as soon the page is called up ,since the page completely dynamic some element only appear after a some action . Since the element is checked even before its created it always troughs a error "No such Element exception"
Sample Code:

```
    public class example
    {

    private IWebElement ExampleElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
                {
                    return d.FindElement(By.Id("ExampleElement ID"));
                });
private IWebElement ExampleElement2 = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
                {
                    return d.FindElement(By.Id("ExampleElement ID"));
                });

    public void example1()
    {
    ExampleElement.click();
    ExampleElement2.click();
    }
    } 

    public class exampleTest
    {
    [Test]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
    example.example1();
    }
    }
```

The ExampleElement2 only loads after the ExampleElement click but what happens is it keeps checking for the ExampleElement2 even before the click action so it is not able to find it and it gives a exception . The thing is i dont want the element to checked for exsistence even before its called for .

I am completely new , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a pattern issue here. Your WebElements are at class level, so when the instance of the class is initiated webdriver is trying to initialize everything and therefore waiting even for Element2. If Element2 is dynamic then you can't wait for it at class level. Wait for it after the condition you expect it to appear.

I would say just have at class level,

```
private IWebElement ExampleElement2;
```

and then, do

```
 public void example1()
    {
    ExampleElement.click();
    ExampleElement2 = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
                {
                    return d.FindElement(By.Id("ExampleElement ID"));
                });
    ExampleElement2.click();
    }
```

Also you might want to look at [PageFactory](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory). You don't want to repeat driver.findElement all over your code and other obvious advantages which are off this topic :-).

Answer (score 0):

As nilesh mentioned in his answer, it's required to defer the loading of the `ExampleElement2`. However it should be an explicit wait and you need to wait for relevant expected condition for example you can say wait until `ElementIsVisible` (in Java API you can put specific conditions like `elementToBeClickable` based on the element type). Then it makes sure the element satisfies the particular condition you passed.

P.S - I am sorry I couldn't help you through a code snippet. Since I am a Java guy I haven't done any Selenium tests using C#. But the principle is same.